# The future of SQLServer Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, message-queue, service-broker

is there any information on the future of the Service Broker infrastructure in SQLServer?
The team's blog ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_service_broker/)) is not very active and there were only minor changes in SQL 2008 R2 release. When building now a distributed system that needs async queueing and there is already a SQLServer / .NET stack in the infrastructure, what are my chances that what I will build will not be obsolete within the next 3 years?

Is there any roadmap available from MS or did someone here something about this on a conference like PDC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tim,

Service Broker will definitely not become obsolete in the next 3 years. It is core functionality of Sql Server and an integral part of Sql Server engine. It is extensively used internally to build core features (DBMail, Event Notifications, Query Notifications etc.) and by customers (e.g MySpace) to build scalable mission critical applications.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Pawel's answer, I'd add some links to sessions that focused on Service Broker at notable conferences:

- [Developing Large Scale Web Applications and Services](http://mschnlnine.vo.llnwd.net/d1/pdc08/WMV-HQ/BB07.wmv) PDC 2008
- [High Performance Distributed Applications in Real World Deployments](http://summit2009.sqlpass.org/Agenda/ProgramSessions/SQLServiceBrokerHighPerformanceDistributedA.aspx) PASS Summit 2009